# Make script on component only apply to one GameObject? Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Using this script to create a component that allows for right button clicks, which I'm using to change a sprite. I've put the script on a few different Game Objects, however when I right click on one game object it changes the sprite of every Game Object that has the component on.

How do I make it so the script only applies to the Game Object it is placed on, and doesn't effect all of the others? Thanks!

```
using UnityEngine;
 using UnityEngine.UI;
 using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
 using UnityEngine.Events;
 using System.Collections;
 [ExecuteInEditMode]
 [AddComponentMenu("Event/RightButtonEvent")]
 public class RightButtonEvent : MonoBehaviour, IPointerEnterHandler, IPointerExitHandler {
     [System.Serializable]public class RightButton : UnityEvent{}
     public RightButton onRightDown;
     public RightButton onRightUp;
     private bool isOver = false;
     void Start () {
     }
 
     void Update () {
         if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1)) {
             onRightDown.Invoke();
         }
         if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(1)) {
             onRightUp.Invoke();
         }
     }
 
     public void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData eventData) {
         isOver = true;
     }
 
     public void OnPointerExit(PointerEventData eventData) {
         isOver = false;
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have the `isOver` flag so simply additionally check it in`Update`

```
 void Update () 
 {
     if(!isOver) return;

     if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1)) {
         onRightDown.Invoke();
     }
     if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(1)) {
         onRightUp.Invoke();
     }
 }

 public void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData eventData) 
 {
     isOver = true;
 }

 public void OnPointerExit(PointerEventData eventData) 
 {
     isOver = false;
     // Would also do this here
     onRightUp.Invoke();
 }
```

---

Instead of `Update` you could actually also implement the [`IPointerDownHandler`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerDownHandler.OnPointerUp.html) and [`IPointerUpHandler`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerUpHandler.OnPointerUp.html) which are only called on the according object in the first place

```
public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    if(eventData.button == InputButton.Right)
    {
        onRightDown.Invoke();
    }
}

public void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    if(eventData.button == InputButton.Right)
    {
        onRightUp.Invoke();
    }
}
```

---

Actually you can also simply use [`void OnMouseDown`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseDown.html) and `OnMouseUp` which also are only called on the according object

> OnMouseDown is called when the user has pressed the mouse button while over the Collider.
>
> This event is sent to all scripts of the GameObject with Collider or GUIElement.

and in there check which mouse button was pressed

```
void OnMouseDown()
{
    if(Input.MouseButtonDown(1))
    {
        onRightDown.Invoke();
    }
}

void OnMouseUp()
{
    if(Input.MouseButtonUp(1))
    {
        onRightUp.Invoke();
    }
}
```